# Chinese characters in watermark not shown properly when iTextSharp is used. Some characters are shown as questionmark

Tags: itext

While adding watermark to the pdf file using iTextSharp, chinese characters are shown as question marks.

I tried with the base font HELVETICA and tried options like CP1252. Also I tried giving the font name which is present in windows fonts and also supports chinese. But every time question marks are displayed in the final pdf file instead of the chinese characters.

Comment: I doubt code page 1252 contains Chinese characters.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Helvetica only contains a limited number of Latin glyphs. As explained in the [iText documentation](http://itextpdf.com/book/), you can't use the font to create Chinese characters. You need a font file, such as `arialuni.ttf` and use it to create a `BaseFont` object. Then use that `BaseFont` object to add a String at an absolute position or to create a `Font` object for use in a high-level object.

Here are some examples:

- How to use a font file such as arialbd.ttf: [EncodingExample](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter11/EncodingExample.cs) In your case, you'd use arialuni.ttf and the encoding IDENTITY_H
- How to use a True Type Collection if you don't have a ttf file: [TTCExample](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter11/TTCExample.cs)
- How to create a string that contains glyphs that require different fonts: [FontSelectionExample](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter11/FontSelectionExample.cs)

All these examples are taken from [chapter 11 of my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=11) about iText. If you browse this documentation, you'll find some PDF examples, such as [font_selection.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter11/font_selection.pdf), [text4.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter14/text4.pdf), etc...

Comment: Can you Please highlight with some sample coding?

Comment: Please click the links in my answer. These links refer to actual, working sample code.